# Python: An example of sharing_get_shared_link_file() in the dropbox API

Tags: python, dropbox

Can anybody share an example of using sharing_get_shared_link_file() method in the dropbox API? I cannot seem to be able to get it working.

I keep getting the error:

'_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'request'

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of using [the `sharing_get_shared_link_file` method](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dropbox.html#dropbox.dropbox.Dropbox.sharing_get_shared_link_file) in [the official Dropbox API v2 Python SDK](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-python) to download a file from Dropbox shared link:

```
import dropbox

ACCESS_TOKEN = "<redacted>"

dbx = dropbox.Dropbox(ACCESS_TOKEN)

shared_link = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/t1emirfeqbnu8tu/hello.txt?dl=0"

metadata, res = dbx.sharing_get_shared_link_file(url=shared_link)

print(metadata)
print(res.text)  # or res.content, or iter_content, or iter_lines, etc. as needed
```

`metadata` is the [`SharedLinkMetadata`](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/sharing.html#dropbox.sharing.SharedLinkMetadata) for the file, and `res` is the [`requests.Response`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/#requests.Response) that you can use to download the file content.

Comment: This is throwing the error: "GetSharedLinkFileError('shared_link_is_directory', None))" at me.

Comment: My example uses a shared link for a specific file. If you're using a shared link for a folder, you need to additionally supply the `path` parameter on `sharing_get_shared_link_file` containing the relative path for the particular file in the linked folder you want to download.

Comment: Is it possible to use sharing_get_shared_link_file without any access token? I want to access a file from publicly shared dropbox file link.

Comment: @FlorianH No, unfortunately `sharing_get_shared_link_file` does require an access token. We'll consider it a feature request though.

Comment: @Greg Thanks. Bit less crucial than I first thought: As changing the `?dl=0` at the end of the DB link url to `?dl=1` allows to readily read the file from within python (e.g. Pandas pd.read_csv).

Comment: @FlorianH Yes, you can use that if that works for you. You can find more information on that here: https://help.dropbox.com/files-folders/share/force-download